# Is it possible to refile using regexp applied to some property?

Tags: regular-expressions, org-refile

If I do `M-x org-refile` on `qux` using the first (commented out) version of `org-refile-targets`, it brings up `Foo`, as expected. Using the second version, I get "No refile targets", whereas I would like `Bar`. Is it too far fetched to ask emacs to do that, or there is a way?

init.el:

```
  (use-package org
    :config
    ;;   (setq org-refile-targets '((nil :tag . "refile"))) ; version 1
        (setq org-refile-targets '((nil :regexp . ".+\n:PROPERTIES:\n:refile:   true\n:END:"))) ; version 2
    )
```

debug.org:

```
* Foo                                                                :refile:

* Bar
:PROPERTIES:
:refile:   true
:END:

* Inbox
** qux
```

[image]

Comment: No, the regexp matches only the headline, not anything after it. `C-h v org-refile-targets` says "... - a cons cell (:regexp . "REGEXP") with a regular expression matching
    *headlines* that are refiling targets.... ". AFAIK, you cannot use a property to specify the target headlines: you'd have to do some preprocessing to find all of them and add them to `org-refile-targets` before you do `org-refile`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an implementation of the preprocessing idea from my comment:

```el
#+begin_src elisp
  (defun my/refiling-headline-list ()
    (org-map-entries (lambda () (nth 4 (org-heading-components))) "refile=\"true\"" 'file))

  (defun my/org-refile-with-properties ()
    (interactive)
    (let ((org-refile-targets `((nil :regexp . ,(mapconcat #'identity (my/refiling-headline-list) "\\|")))))
      (org-refile)))
#+end_src
```

Then instead of `M-x org-refile`, you do `M-x my/org-refile-with-properties`.

We let-bind `org-refile-targets` around a call to `org-refile`, where we set the variable using the `:regexp` specification, with a regexp that consists of the headlines of all the sections that have a `refile` property that is equal to `true`. We construct that regexp by concatenating all such headlines with a `\|` alternation operator between the headlines (we have to double the backslash in the string).

The list of headlines with the given property is obtained by calling `org-map-entries`: it visits each headline in the file that matches the property and applies a function on each one, where in this case the function just returns the text of the headline. `org-map-properties`, like all mapping functions, returns a list of all the results.

See the doc string of `org-map-entries` for information about the function and its arguments: `C-h f org-map-entries`. More information and some examples are available in the section  [Using the Mapping API](https://orgmode.org/manual/Using-the-Mapping-API.html) in the Org mode manual. You can also search this site for `org-map-entries`: there are many examples of its use.

In the example, calling `my/refiling-headline-list` would return the list `("Bar")` since that's the only headline with the property. In general, it would return a list of all such headlines: `("Bar" "Baz" ...)`. In the latter case, the `mapconcat` call would return the string `"Bar\\|Baz\\|..."` with all the headline strings concatenated and separated by an alternation operator.

This implementation only works for the current file: the refile targets have to be in the same file as the item to be refiled; that limitation comes about by the very simple implementation of `my/refiling-headline-list` which only looks in the current file and by the `nil` file specification in the let-binding of `org-refile-targets` in `my/org-refile-with-properties`. It is quite possible to extend it so that the refile targets from multiple files are made available, but for now, that's left as an exercise for the interested reader.

Comment: IT worked. I expected a 3 instead of `nth 4`... I presume `'file` stands for current file. Where would I find this?

Comment: See the last paragraph of the (edited) answer for the current-file limitation.  `C-h f org-map-entries` describes the function and its arguments and the [Using the Mapping API](https://orgmode.org/manual/Using-the-Mapping-API.html) in the manual has a more extended description and some examples. In addition, I and others have used it a number of times in answers on Emacs SE, so searching the site for `org-map-entries` should provide more examples.

Comment: Do you mean you expected `(nth 3 ...)` rather than `(nth 4 ...)`? `org-heading-components` returns  a list `(level reduced-level todo priority headline tags)` so the `headline` that I want to extract is the fifth element of the returned list. `nth` starts counting from 0, so `(nth 4 ...)` returns that fifth element (which is *not* starring Milla Jovovich or Bruce Willis...)

Comment: I tested this further, it won't work unless the heading whose property meets the requirement is unique. For instance in this set up, the refiled entry will come under the first Inbox.
`* bar\n** Inbox\n* foo\n** Inbox\n:PROPERTIES:\n:refile:   true\n:END:\n`. To discriminate among nodes with identical headings I was thinking about replacing `refile: true` with `refile:[identifier]` and prompting the identifier in place of the heading. But I haven't been able to pull it off.

Comment: That's the disadvantage of using a general mechanism like regexps to search for a headline: uniqueness in headline names is required in order for the search to find a single result. You could decorate all the entries that `my/refiling-headline-list` returns in the list with the `point` of the headline where the property is found (so the return value would be `((<headline> <pos>) ...)`, i.e. a list of two-element lists) and then use `rfloc` to zero-in on a specific headline.

Comment: I solved the problem in case you haven't noticed it.

Comment: Sorry - I didn't notice. Yes, that's basically what I had in mind except for the `org-element-*` usage which is probably the better way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my last comment, here's the first half of a possible answer. Speculative: the second half would consist in invoking `org-refile` using [RFLOC](https://github.com/emacsmirror/org/blob/master/lisp/org-refile.el).

```
#+begin_src elisp
(defun my/get-refile-value-begin ()
  ;; (interactive)
  (let ((tree (org-element-parse-buffer 'headline))
        (matches '()))
    (org-element-map tree 'headline
      (lambda (element)
        (when (org-element-property :REFILE element)
          (push (list (org-element-property :REFILE element) (org-element-property :begin element)) matches)))
      nil nil nil)
    matches)) ;; C-x C-e
#end_src
```

Notice this oddity: `:refile` is internally stored as `:REFILE`.

Update: this work for either of `foo` or `bar` using the sample buffer.

```
#+begin_src elisp
(defun my/org-refile ()
  (interactive)
  (let* ((rfloc-pairs (my/get-refile-value-begin))
         (rfloc-values (mapcar #'car rfloc-pairs))
         (the-value (completing-read "Select refile target: " rfloc-values nil t))
         (rfloc-match (assoc the-value rfloc-pairs)))
        (org-refile nil nil (list (car rfloc-match) (buffer-file-name) nil (car (cdr rfloc-match)))))) ;; C-x C-e
#end_src
```

Buffer:

```
* bar
** Inbox
:PROPERTIES:
:refile: bar
:END:

* foo
** Inbox
:PROPERTIES:
:refile: foo
:END:

# C-x C-e after:
(my/get-refile-value-begin) 
# yields:
# (("foo" 1201) ("bar" 1153))
```

Envisaged workflow:

1. `org-capture RET key RET new entry`
2. `my/org-refile RET foo|bar`
3. Manually rearrange `new entry` inside the chosen target

[image]

[image][image]

Comment: I didn't know about the upper-casing of property names, but it is documented in the doc string of `org-element-headline-parser`. I believe the reason is that all the standard properties that the parser itself adds to the returned parse tree (`:begin`, `:end`, `:contents-begin` etc) are in lower case, so upper-casing user-defined properties makes sure that they don't conflict  with those.