# What function is behind org-agenda matching?

Tags: org-agenda

I'd like to identify entries nested under entry `foo` that don't match `under="foo"`. If I do `M-x org-agenda RET m under<>"foo"`, I get the matches across all files specified in `org-agenda-files` = overkill. What would be sensible ways to approach this problem?

```
* foo
** A
:PROPERTIES:
:under:    foo
:END:
** B
:PROPERTIES:
:under:    bar
:END:
** C
:PROPERTIES:
:under:    foo
:END:
* bar
** D
:PROPERTIES:
:under:    bar
:END:
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a very general method of changing the behavior of a function that depends on a global variable: you let-bind the variable to a different value around the call to the function. In this particular case, you can let-bind `org-agenda-files` to a list consisting of the current file only and call whatever function the `m` key in the agenda menu calls. When that function decides what files to apply itself to, it will consult the variable, find the let-bound value and proceed with that - the global value is shadowed by the let-bound value. In fact I used this method in the [answer to a different question of yours](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/77004/14825) where I let bound `org-refile-targets` around a call to `org-refile` -- that attests to the method's generality and applicability to different circumstances.

In this case, the `m` key in the org agenda menu calls the function `org-tags-view` (do `C-h f org-agenda` to see that). So we can do the following:

```el
(defun my/org-tags-view ()
   (interactive)
   (let ((org-agenda-files (list (buffer-file-name))))
     (org-tags-view)))
```

Now call it with `M-x my/org-tags-view`.

---

EDIT 1: In fact, it's not necessary to use `org-tags-view`. You can use `org-sparse-tree` which limits itself to the current buffer: `C-c /`

---

EDIT 2: I missed the other half of the question (not an excuse: that's partly the reason that it's a good idea to have *one* question per question), but it is not difficult to do what you want. Your search `m RET under<>"foo"` already does most of the job. To finish it, all you have to do is find the `foo` subtree and narrow the view to the subtree: `C-x n s` bound to `org-narrow-to-subtree`. Of course, you can do the narrowing first if you want. Narrowing is not specific to Org mode (although narrowing a subtree definitely is): you can narrow to a region in general. Undoing the narrowing is called `widening` and is done with `M-x widen` which is bound to `C-x n w`.

Comment: This locally resets `org-agenda-files` to `buffer-file-name` and then invokes `org-tags-view` which is the function behind the functionality considered: that's insightful, but it solves only ½ of the problem. The other  ½ in the use case: "[only] entries nested under entry foo"

Comment: `M-x org-sparse-subtree m RET under<>"foo"` does most of the job, but `org-narrow-to-subtree` on `foo` would have to come first. And the problem is, I don't know how to undo it: clicking on "mouse-2 remove narrowing from buffer" does nothing.

Comment: I did the narrowing last and it seemed to work fine: what problem are you having? As for undoing the narrowing,  `C-x n w` (bound to `widen`) should do it.

Comment: Remider to m/s: undo `M-x org-sparse-tree RET m RET topic="foo"` with `C-c C-c`.